# Doing an unwind using Collection.Group() in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I need to unwind an array in order to do a group by in some existing code using the mongo Collection.Group() method.

I have a document like:

```
{
    "_id" : "5373c4fdcb080a06d471c07b",
    "Form" : "Form 1",
    "Values" : {
        "Name" : "Bob Smith",
        "FavColors" : [ 
            "green",
            "blue"
        ]
    }
}
```

I need to unwind the FavColors array and group by FavColors in order to get a count like this:

green    1
blue     1

I understand this can easily be completed using the aggregation framework, but is there anyway to unwind an array using Collection.Group() in the C# driver or db.Collection.Group() in you are in the mongo shell?  i.e. Is there anything analogous to $unwind from the aggregation framework in the .group operator?

Comment: No there is not, `$unwind` is an operator of the aggregation framework and it is the better method to use. The `.group()` method is JavaScript based as opposed to the native C++ implementation that the aggregation framework does. mapReduce gives you more control over JavaScript but is therefore still based on that engine. There should be no reason why you cannot implement the `aggregate` method instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
function groupByFavColors(host){
 var conn = new Mongo(host);
 var db = conn.getDatabase("DB-NAME");

 var res = db.product.aggregate([
     {
         // unwind the array
         $unwind: '$Values.FavColors',
     },
     {
         // group by..
         $group: {
             _id: '$Values.FavColors',

             num_sold: {
                 $sum: 1
             }
         }
     }
 ]);

 printjson(res);

}

print("usage: groupbyFavColors(string host);")
```

Comment: This answer is using the aggregation framework.  The problem I'm having is that I have existing code written using the .group operator that I need to modify to unwind the array.

Comment: @Brantino The answer is correct because the $unwind belongs to the aggregation framework. You are using the wrong method.

Comment: You can not unwind an array using the group method, cause its grouping using a "key" which is a field in the document,then its gives you a reduce method where you can add your groupby logic and return the aggregated value for the reduced document

Comment: @NeilLunn I understand that $unwind is part of the aggregation framework, but I'm constrained to using .Group by some existing code.  I'm trying to figure out if the existing code using .group can be modified to unwind the array without completely rewriting to use the aggregation framework, but it doesn't look like that is possible.

Comment: @Brantino yes, you are right, this is unfortunately not possible, regardless of what SDK you use.

Comment: @Brantino wouldn't you just iterate the nested value in JS (the reduce/map function of group) and then emit the nested values, that is like unwinding but for the group function...man, the group function was a really bad choice for whoever coded that block